# Optimization of the solution to an ODE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, symbolic, pure-function

Apologies if this is obvious -- I'm very new to *Mathematica*.

I'm trying to minimize the solution to an ODE with respect to a variable. The following code generates the solution to the ODE,

```
sol=DSolve[
  {(1/2) * σ^2 * k''[q] + μ*k'[q] - λ*k[q] == 0, 
   k'[0] == -mc, k'[b] == me}, k, q]
```

but when I try minimizing using the `Minimize` (with respect to only q) command,

```
Minimize[k[q] /.First@sol, q]
```

I'm coming up empty -- it should return the minimum value of k(q)* in terms of $b, \lambda, \mu, \sigma$, $me$ and $mc$ as well as q* in terms of $b, \lambda, \mu, \sigma$, $me$ and $mc$.

*** Update ***

The following code works (thank you @bbgodfrey):

```
s = Simplify[k[q] /. DSolve[{(1/2)*σ^2*k''[q] + μ*k'[q] - λ*k[q] == 0,k'[0] == -mc, k'[b] == me}, k[q], q][[1, 1]]]
sq=q /. Solve[D[s, q] == 0, q][[2, 1]]
kq = Simplify[s /. q -> sq]
```

But a second minimization with respect to b of the function

```
Gq = kq + b*\[Gamma]
```

I start to run into trouble again. I try:

```
Minimize[Gq,b]
```

returns unevaluated.  This also doesn't work:

```
sb=b/. Solve[D[Gq, b] == 0, b]
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Specifically what code have you written to use `Minimize`? I am also not sure that I understand your double-minimization requirements. Could you expand on that? Also, consider `sol = DSolve[...]; k[q] /. First@sol`: that should give you the function you want to minimize.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for the response! I clarified the question to eliminate the confusion (I think the second optimization step will be easy once I get the first one to work) and also added code for minimization (but I think I'm doing this wrong!). Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5):

A slight variant of the code in the question yields

```
s = Simplify[k[q] /. DSolve[{(1/2)*σ^2*k''[q] + μ*k'[q] - λ*k[q] == 0,
    k'[0] == -mc, k'[b] == me}, k[q], q][[1, 1]]]

(* (E^(-((q (μ + Sqrt[μ^2 + 2 λ σ^2]))/σ^2)) (E^((2 q Sqrt[μ^2 + 2 λ σ^2])/σ^2)
    mc λ σ^2 + E^((2 q Sqrt[μ^2 + 2 λ σ^2] + b (μ + Sqrt[μ^2 + 2 λ σ^2]))/σ^2)
   me λ σ^2 + E^((2 b Sqrt[μ^2 + 2 λ σ^2])/σ^2) mc (μ^2 + λ σ^2 - μ Sqrt[μ^2 + 
   2 λ σ^2]) + E^((b (μ + Sqrt[μ^2 + 2 λ σ^2]))/σ^2) me (μ^2 + λ σ^2 - 
   μ Sqrt[μ^2 + 2 λ σ^2])))/((-1 + E^((2 b Sqrt[μ^2 + 
   2 λ σ^2])/σ^2)) λ (-μ + Sqrt[μ^2 + 2 λ σ^2])) *)
```

Indeed, `Minimize[s, q]` returns unevaluated.  However, the solution can be obtained by hand, so to speak, by solving `D[s, q] == 0` for `q`.

```
q /. Solve[D[s, q] == 0, q][[1, 1]]

(* (σ^2 Log[-((E^((b Sqrt[μ^2 + 2 λ σ^2])/(2 σ^2)) 
   Sqrt[E^((b Sqrt[μ^2 + 2 λ σ^2])/σ^2) mc + E^((b μ)/σ^2) me])/
   Sqrt[mc + E^((b μ)/σ^2 + (b Sqrt[μ^2 + 2 λ σ^2])/σ^2)
   me])])/Sqrt[μ^2 + 2 λ σ^2] *)
```

Presumably, minimization with respect to other parameters can be computed in a similar, although algebraically tedious, manner.

Comment: This is great for finding q* -- I'm getting stuck trying to get k(q*) though also. Is there an easy way to put q* back into the function to get k(q*)?

Comment: (Also, what does [[1,1]] do?) Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Karthik  If you name the second result `sq` (not `q*`, which is not valid syntax), then `s/.q->sq` gives `k[sq]`.  Look up `Rule` in the documentation.  `[[1,1]]` eliminates the extra curly brackets in the first answer, which sometimes get in the way.  Look up `Part` in the documentation.

Comment: One could also choose to use `DSolveValue[]` to avoid `Part[]` gymnastics in this case.

Comment: @J.M.  True.  I chose to remain with `DSolve` to keep close to the original code,.  Of course, "close" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @bbgodfrey  Thank you! This is extremely helpful. I'm trying to do my second minimization: Gq = k[sq] + b*\[Gamma] with respect to b and it's coming back again as unevaluated with Minimize. I try analogous code: sb=b/. Solve[D[Gq, b] == 0, b] but this doesn't work either. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: @Karthik  Specific question: What is `[Gamma]`?  General observation: `sq` contains branch cuts, so a minimum probably cannot be determined without assumptions on the numerous variables.  By the way, `σ` can be scaled out of the problem.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: \[Gamma] (as well as \[Lamda], me, mc, and b) are all strictly positive parameters. \[Sigma] can be zero or positive. And \[Mu] can be negative, zero, or positive.

Comment: @Karthik  `γ` does not appear in your ODE, so I do not understand why you are introducing it here.   `σ` cannot be set to `0`, unless one of the boundary conditions is eliminated.  With `σ != 0`, it can be eliminated by rescaling other constants, which I recommend you do.  Other analytical simplifications also may be possible.  Investigating such possibilities before trying to minimize `k` over so many constants will make your life easier.